# Group products in table javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table-bordered" width="100%">

<tr>

<th>Product</th>
<th>Cnt</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 1</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 2</td>
<td>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 1</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 1</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

I need: remove duplicate products, and add up the amount it. How I can do this?
I think, that need javascript or jquery, but How I can remove duplicates and write cnt to other product?

I need this table on result:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table-bordered" width="100%">

<tr>

<th>Product</th>
<th>Cnt</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 1</td>
<td>24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 2</td>
<td>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You've shown no attempt at solving this on your own. What have you tried? What didn't work? What, *specifically*, are you having trouble with? Consider editing your question and providing an attempt of any sort. Right now your question reads as if you're relying on StackOverflow to be a free code-writing service.

Comment: right answer give NaN, are you sure?

Comment: @VadimHulevich sorry, you're right

Comment: @VadimHulevich Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    const tbl = document.getElementById("clearTable");
    const existProducts = {};
    [].forEach.call(tbl.querySelectorAll("tr td:first-child"), function(el) {
        if (existProducts[el.textContent]) {
            existProducts[el.textContent].count = existProducts[el.textContent].count + parseFloat(el.nextElementSibling.textContent);
            existProducts[el.textContent].el.nextElementSibling.textContent = existProducts[el.textContent].count;
            el.parentNode.remove();
        } else {
            existProducts[el.textContent] = {
                count: (existProducts[el.textContent] || 0) + parseFloat(el.nextElementSibling.textContent),
                el:el
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <table id="clearTable" class="table-bordered" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Cnt</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 1</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 2</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 1</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 1</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all wrap all the content rows in `tbody` and then you should map product name as key and sum all the counts:

```js
var contentMap = {};
var contentRows = $('tbody tr').each(function() {
  var columns = $(this).find('td');
  console.log(columns);
  var value = parseInt(columns.eq(1).text(), 10);
  var key = columns.eq(0).text();
  if (!contentMap[key]) {
    contentMap[key] = 0;
  }
  contentMap[key] += value;
});
var tbody = $('tbody').empty();
Object.keys(contentMap).forEach(function(key) {
  tbody.append($('<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + contentMap[key] + '</td>'));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-bordered" width="100%">

  <tr>

    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Cnt</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gudzdanil/54Lc3yjd/6/

Comment: This answer may or may not be correct, however more importantly, OP has done *nothing* to solve this on their own - you've written their code for them from scratch. While this may help one person (OP), it hurts the rest of the community, because it encourages bad questions.

Comment: @TylerRoper got it

Comment: @DanilGudz thanks, it worked

Comment: i fixed my solution to